# Does Chrome share cookies between different profiles?

Tags: google-chrome, facebook

I used to open Facebook in one Chrome profile and do shopping from another one. that was good until I recently noticed that Facebook suggests ads for things I was looking for in another profile. Is it Chrome sharing cookies between profiles or just that Facebook has become so weird when it comes to privacy issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't share cookies between profiles. Each profile has its own data directory so that nothing is shared at all.

You can read more about where to find your user data on this page: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/user_data_dir.md

Your next suspicion is valid: Facebook has tracking mechanisms that work even when you're not visiting Facebook directly, even if you're not logged in.

If a website you visit has any kind of integration with Facebook (Login with Facebook, like or share buttons, Facebook ads) then that enables Facebook to track what you are doing on that website. Even if you don't click any of those things.

You can read more about how that works on this page: https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/data-off-facebook/

Comment: the thing is i am using fb from one profile, visiting other sites from different one. How on Earth fb track what i am visiting even with different profile. 
I suspect that chrome is some way has a bug enables fb to track the user no matter what profile he is using

Comment: It's not a Chrome bug, it's just that Facebook is smarter than that. Even if you use different profiles, FB can still detect that it's the same person.

Comment: IP, user agent, time